# double barplot to compare columns

Tags: r, bar-chart

I created a data frame of data:

data <-

```
          element      ova.x   testes.x       ova.y    testes.y
1         Dong-1  0.34000000 1.1200000   0.06694795 2.89051799
```

My goal is to create a bar chart that compares value ova.x,ova.y testes.x,testes.y  for the given element obtaining something like this:
[image]
 assuming that speciesA is ova.x, testes.x and speciesB is ova.y, testes.y and Gene1 is Ova, gene 2 is testes. 
I don't know how to plot these data

I've tried using `plotly` but it doesn't give me the expected result:

```
library(plotly)

Tissues <- c("ova", "testes")
TE <- c("0.34000000", "1.1200000")
geni <- c("0.06694795", "2.89051799")
dati <- data.frame(Tissues, TE, geni)

p <- plot_ly(dati, x = ~Tissues, y = ~TE, type = 'bar', name = 'TE') %>%
    add_trace(y = ~geni, name = 'GENES') %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
```

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish. What would your desired plot look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: ok, you're right. I'll put an example on my  topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?
You can use gather() function from tidyr package

```
library(tidyr)
dati2 <- dati %>% gather(key = "variable",value =  "value", c(TE,geni))
ggplot(dati2, aes(Tissues, value, fill =variable))+
geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]